# Warning message during boot after installation of kernel 3.3: Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch

Tags: 11.10, boot, kernel

I have Ubuntu Server 11.10 and after installation of kernel 3.3 (I just followed instructions from site [www.upbuntu.com - How To Install Linux 3.3 Kernel In Ubuntu 11.10/12.04](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-install-linux-33-kernel-in.html)) It shows me following message during boot:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda5: clean, 204099/1152816 files, 988854/4608639 blocks
/dev/sda6: clean, 2345/1281120 files, 142711/5120710 blocks
modem-manager[830]:   ModemManager (version 0.5) starting...


 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon [154G[ OK ]
 * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server [154G[ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems [154G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems [154G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility [154G[ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay [154G[ OK ]
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/bin.ping (/etc/apparmor.d/bin.ping line 28): profile /bin/ping network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session (/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session line 71): profile /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient (/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient line 73): profile /sbin/dhclient network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.klogd (/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.klogd line 35): profile /sbin/klogd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslog-ng (/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslog-ng line 52): profile /sbin/syslog-ng network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslogd (/etc/apparmor.d/sbin.syslogd line 40): profile /sbin/syslogd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser line 165): profile /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser line 165): profile browser_java network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser line 165): profile browser_openjdk network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince line 142): profile /usr/bin/evince network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince line 142): profile /usr/bin/evince-previewer network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince line 142): profile /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.deliver (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.deliver line 24): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.dovecot-auth (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.dovecot-auth line 24): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.imap (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.imap line 23): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/imap network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.imap-login (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.imap-login line 22): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.managesieve-login (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.managesieve-login line 22): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve-login network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.pop3 (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.pop3 line 22): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3 network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.pop3-login (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.dovecot.pop3-login line 21): profile /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.telepathy (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.telepathy line 86): profile /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.telepathy (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.telepathy line 86): profile /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-* network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.avahi-daemon (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.avahi-daemon line 30): profile /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd line 170): profile /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf network rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd line 170): profile /usr/sbin/cupsd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dnsmasq (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dnsmasq line 51): profile /usr/sbin/dnsmasq network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dovecot (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dovecot line 37): profile /usr/sbin/dovecot network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.identd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.identd line 31): profile /usr/sbin/identd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mdnsd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mdnsd line 35): profile /usr/sbin/mdnsd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld line 44): profile /usr/sbin/mysqld network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.nmbd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.nmbd line 21): profile /usr/sbin/nmbd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.nscd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.nscd line 46): profile /usr/sbin/nscd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.smbd (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.smbd line 40): profile /usr/sbin/smbd network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump line 64): profile /usr/sbin/tcpdump network rules not enforced
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.traceroute (/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.traceroute line 26): profile /usr/sbin/traceroute network rules not enforced
 * Starting AppArmor profiles        [160G 
 [154G[ OK ]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Checking for running unattended-upgrades:
```

What does this warnings mean and how can I fix it?

Informations about my system:

```
response@response:~$ uname -a
Linux response 3.3.0-030300-generic #201203182135 SMP Mon Mar 19 01:43:18 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It seems they do not have 3.3 patches hosted yet.